# How to use grape-entity without grape-api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape, grape-api

I am trying to use grape-entity without the grape-api gem. So just use it as a serializers for raw rails controllers.

When trying to present my resource by doing:

`present User.all, with: Entities::User`

I get that the `present` method is undefined

How am I suppose to present those resources using the entity? The documentation says to use `present`

Comment: can you try `Entities::User.represent User.all` ?

Answer (score 4):

I needed to use Grape Entity as well, outside of Grape (in a basic Rails controller), and I ended up using Chris suggestion:

`Entities::MyResource.represent MyResource.first`

It works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Additional tip: Once you have an instance of the entity representing the object, you can call `serializable_hash` on it